# How to determine if a user clicked on a tab inside of a TabHost?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I have a TabHost with two tabs. I want to know when the user clicks on either tab. How can I achieve this?

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Main.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("watchlist").setIndicator("Watchlist",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ARActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("trending").setIndicator("Trending",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. When the user clicks a tab, the tabs will change and the activity inside the new tab will become active therefore it will already 'know' that its tab was clicked.

Comment: Is there a way to add an onclick listener to the tabs so that I can do some stuff at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use an onTabChangeListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html) and pass that to the TabHost. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener%28android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener%29

You can effectively get notified every time someone switches a tab.